# Rust LinkedList second mutable borrow while moving first item to the end

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Good day!
I was trying to move the first item to the end in a linked list.
I have a linked list like this:

```
let mut list = LinkedList::new();
list.push_back('a');
list.push_back('b');
list.push_back('c');
```

If I move item like this:

```
list.push_back(list.pop_front().unwrap());
```

Rust would throw an "second mutable borrow occurs" error.

But If a get the first item at another line of code:

```
let str = list.pop_front().unwrap();
list.push_back(str);
```

Then it's fine.

Why these two pieces of code behave differently? I totally don't understand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `push_back` and `pop_front` are methods that keep a mutable reference to list, so you can't do this:

```
list.push_back(list.pop_front().unwrap());
```

Doing it the other way that you pointed out works because you drop the mutable reference at the end of the first line:

```
let str = list.pop_front().unwrap(); // mutable reference dropped here, so it's fine to have another mutable reference afterwards
list.push_back(str);
```

Comment: Thanks! But for the first one, why it won't drop the mutable reference after `list.pop_front().unwrap()` returns?

Comment: Afaik, the compiler can't infer that. It statically analyzes the code one line at a time.